# ASP MVC 2 application looging to IIS 7

Tags: logging, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering, does IIS 7 have any api to use for logging the asp mvc application?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of logging do you need? IIS 7 has it's own built in logging system which can be found as "Logging" in the IIS Group in Feature View.